# Create a new column based on condition of another column with apply lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have the following df:

| operator_id | total_records | avg_wait_time | is_missed_call | out_calls_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 879896.0 | 117 | 17.958253 | 47 |
| 1 | 879898.0 | 227 | 17.239858 | 89 |
| 2 | 880020.0 | 20 | 6.815000 | 6 |
| 3 | 880022.0 | 70 | 16.172996 | 29 |

I try to create a new column named 'test', that will show the precentage of out_calls_cnt of total_records, using a condition that out_calls_cnt is greater then 1, else,  the function should return 0.

I assume looping with a row function will be inefficient.

My code:

```
dataset_operators['test'] = dataset_operators[['out_calls_cnt', 'total_records']].apply(lambda x:  dataset_operators['out_calls_cnt'] / dataset_operators['total_rows'] if dataset_operators['out_calls_cnt'] > 10 else 0, axis = 1)
```

got the error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I would like to try and solve it using lambda, even though I manageed to solve it using using where:

```
dataset_operators['test'] = (dataset_operators['out_calls_cnt'] / dataset_operators['total_records']).where(dataset_operators['out_calls_cnt'] > 10, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative using `np.where`, with your shown samples, try following. This will create a new column named `test` in df, you could change it as per your need too.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['test'] = np.where(df['out_calls_cnt']>10,df['out_calls_cnt'] / df['total_records'],0)
```

Comment: wheres the lambda here ?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend not to use apply and use your second solution using `where` but since you specifically ask for it, You can do the below, replace `dataset_operators` in your lambda call with `x`

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['out_calls_cnt'] / x['total_records'] 
                   if x['out_calls_cnt'] > 10 else 0, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Would you recommend it because the where method is more efficient?